# Error while returning the first non-repeating character

Tags: java, string, loops, arraylist, char

I want to return only the first non-repeating character of my `String` but instead, it returns my desired answer and the value of `str`. How can I make it return only the character and not my input?

The below code:

```
public class Main {
    public static String getNumber(String str) {
        for (char i : str.toCharArray()) {
            if (str.indexOf(i) == str.lastIndexOf(i)) {
                System.out.println("First non-repeating character is: " + i);
                break;
            }
        }

        return str;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(getNumber(s.nextLine()));
    }
}
```

Input:

```
 "abcdef"
```

Output:

```
First non-repeating character is: a
"abcdef"
```

Comment: Well, you might want to get rid of that ` System.out.print()` in your main method since you're already printing in `GetNumber()` (btw, as per Java code conventions it should be `getNumber()` and from a design perspective the name is misleading).

Comment: It's a technical assessment test, they make it tricky

Comment: `GetNumber` is the wrong name for your method. One, the method does not get any number. Two, a method name should start with a lower case letter. When posting to Stack Overflow, in your own best interest make your code as readable and self-explanatory as you can. It greatly increases the chances that someone here will read and understand it.

Comment: I personally think it would be better to just return the first non-repeating character...as a `char` type. Then you just need to do this within the method: `for (char i : str.toCharArray()) { if (str.indexOf(i) == str.lastIndexOf(i)) { return i; } } return '\0';`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using the `String.valueOf` method to wrap the char variable:

```
for (char i : str.toCharArray()) {
    if (str.indexOf(i) == str.lastIndexOf(i)) {
        str = String.valueOf(i);
        break;
    }
}

return str;
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a correct answer to your own question. Using the same variable `str` for both parameter and return value may confuse those reading your code. I recommend that you either introduce a second variable (say, `result`) or simply return `String.valueOf(i)` from within your loop (then you also don’t need `break;` any more).